# How do I force Stata to place a horizontal line above all other plots in a graph?

Tags: stata, graphing

I'm graphing a time series and shading certain time periods based on a Boolean indicator variable in Stata 13.1 on Windows 7. Time periods are shaded if the indicator variable equals 1, and not shaded if it's missing. I want to draw a horizontal line at the point on the y-axis where the time series equals 0. Here is an example, using the `freduse` plugin (`ssc install freduse, replace`):

```
freduse GDPC1 USRECQ, clear
gen qrtr = qofd(daten)
tsset qrtr, q
drop date*

drop if qrtr < tq(1947q1)
replace USRECQ = . if !USRECQ
label var USRECQ "Recession"

gen ly = log(GDPC1)
tsfilter hp lydev = ly, smooth(1600)

#delimit ;
twoway (scatter USRECQ qrtr,
           recast(area)
           bcolor(gs13)
           cmissing(n)
           yaxis(1)
           ylabel(0 1)
           yscale(off))  
       (tsline lydev,
           yaxis(2)
           yscale(alt axis(2))
           ytitle("Deviation from trend", axis(2))),
       yline(0, axis(2))
;
#delimit cr
```

`ly_dev` is the time series, and `USRECQ` is the indicator variable. In practice, the indicator variable could be anything, which is why I don't want to hard code the values to shade in the `twoway` command, as seen in [this Statalist post](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2003-06/msg00121.html) or the `nber` plugin in the SSC. This code produces this graph:

[image: Incorrect plot]

The horizontal line is obscured by the shading because the shading is created first, but I need the shading to be created first because otherwise, it obscures the plot of the time series (since Stata doesn't support transparency/alpha blending).

Is it possible to force Stata to place this horizontal line on top of all other plots in the graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; this can be done. But you have to apply minor force.

In essence, the idea behind `yline()` and similar options is to supply reference lines, which are never to be plotted on top of the data.

So, to subvert that you have to supply your line as data. One way to do that is just to define a variable which is constant and plot it as a `line` graph.

The technique below is more general in not assuming that the added line need be horizontal.

First for convenience, we calculate the endpoints of the line and put them in local macros. In other examples, this may be dispensable.

```
local t1 = tq(1947q1)
local t2 = tq(2014q2)
```

Now the key is to fire up `twoway scatteri` but to recast the two points (in this case) to a line. As we supply two pairs of coordinates the result is a single straight line (which happens to be horizontal). You want a line which corresponds with 0 on the second *y*  axis:

```
(scatteri 0 `t1' 0 `t2', recast(line) yaxis(2))
```

For similar problems, one should be able to calculate the appropriate coordinates from the  data in each case or fall back on a constant variable plotted as a horizontal line graph.

EDIT: Revised version benefits from comments by Roberto Ferrer.

EDIT 2022:  See paper at https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0067 and blog post at https://blog.stata.com/2020/02/13/adding-recession-shading-to-time-series-graphs/

Comment: If the original poster doesn't like manually inputting data I think it would suffice to specify the `yaxis(2)` option for `scatteri` along with zeros. For the endpoints of the straight line (locals `t1` and `t2`), he could `summarize qrtr` and save `r(min)` and `r(max)` in locals. This worked for me with his example data: ``(scatteri 0 `t1' 0 `t2', yaxis(2) recast(line))``

Comment: @Roberto Good points. Feel free to edit your comment into my answer.

Comment: I'm sure the answer needs no defending, but I wonder why the downvote. The core of a solution is right there.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer, @Nick Cox : Thank you for the help; I much prefer to use `scatteri` with the `yaxis(2)` option instead of manually calculating a y value (0.6) to place the line on the [0, 1] axis, which seems potentially fraught with error. Either `summarize` or `tsreport` work for calculating the end points of the time series, so between the answer and the comment, I have all the components of a solution. Thank you again.

Comment: @Roberto Ferrer I noticed that. Usual kind of comment to downvoter, whoever you are: I would welcome your better answer to this question, or your reason for the downvote.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for the answer. My personal preference is that specifying `yaxis(2)` in the `scatteri` command is more elegant than manually mapping 0 on the second axis to 0.6 on the first axis, but the answer is quite useful regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, little late to the party, but maybe this helps people like me who searched for this problem like me. I think I found an easy to implement solution for the example:

```
    g constant_zero=0
    (connected constant_zero qrtr, yaxis(2) msymbol(none) lcolor(red) lpattern(dash))
```

For a horizontal line from 0 to 10 more generally:

```
    g constant_zero=0
    g xline_var=_n-1
    twoway (connected constant0 xline_var if xline_var<11,msymbol(none) lpattern(dash))
```

For a vertical line from 0 to 10:

```
    g constant_zero=0
    g yline_var=_n-1

    twoway (connected yline_var constant_zero if yline_var<11,msymbol(none) lpattern(dash))
```

If you need more finegrained ends of the line, just divide the yline_var or xline_var by 10, 100 or whatever you need.

Comment: This is fine, and you have a solution you like. So good. But this approach is already mentioned in the previous answer and it has no advantages and a few small disadvantages. You need to `generate` a new variable and then it is hanging around in your dataset, which are tiny problems, but not zero.  Note also that something like `scatter mpg weight || function 21, ra(weight)` adds a line at 21 without creating a new variable. Choose your own constant and your own range.  In either case, a legend may need attention.